# Disk corrupted ? One folder cannot access

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk, disk

I have one Disk for backup on my PC that I copy some files.
I have a lot of Folders and Data on this disk but I get this error message only for one folder. Do I need another disk?

I Run  `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` but with no luck same error message.

Should I delete the Downloads folder?

I try to delete Downloads but no luck also

```
└─[0] <> ls -lh    
ls: cannot access 'Downloads': Input/output error
total 69K
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 1 me me 4,0K Dec 26 19:32 me
```

I also ran smartctl and it said healthy.

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

**Disk**

```
Model Family:     SAMSUNG SpinPoint F4 EG (AF) 
Device Model:     SAMSUNG HD204UI 
Type: HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

dmesg

```
[92409.430263] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x800000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[92409.430269] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[92409.430274] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[92409.430283] ata5.00: cmd 60/08:b8:00:ec:34/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 41/40:00:00:ec:34/00:00:04:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[92409.430288] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[92409.430293] ata5.00: error: { UNC }
[92409.442525] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[92409.442546] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92409.442551] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92409.442554] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[92409.442559] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 04 34 ec 00 00 00 08 00
[92409.442563] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 70577152 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[92409.442570] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 8821888, async page read
[92409.442591] ata5: EH complete
```

Comment: Looks like the disk is fine. Have you run fsck against that disk? That should fix any file system issues.

Comment: I try sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Does `dmesg` or `mount -l` tell you anything interesting?

Usually the question marks imply that file attributes cannot be found. Something could be corrupted with the way the disk/filesystem has been mounted and/or inodes cannot be read or found. I've seen it plenty of times before over a network with CIFS.

Have you tried remounting?

Comment: i add dmesg msg, i try mount it again same error

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the

```
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? Downloads
```

means you currently have only `r` permission (= read directory listing) to the parent directory of `Downloads`, but the `x` permission (= to access the contents of the directory) is missing. As a result, when the `ls` command is running `stat()` on the `Downloads` directory, it gets an "access denied" error and cannot report any information other than just the name and the fact that it's a directory.

But the `ls: cannot access 'Downloads': Input/output error` certainly suggests it's not a permissions issue, but possibly something worse.

On the other hand, if the filesystem on the disk is NTFS, the error response might just mean there is some NTFS-specific permissions issue that does not exactly fit the POSIX standard definition of error responses from `stat()`.

For NTFS, I think Windows's "Check this disk for errors" is still better at NTFS checking than any NTFS `fsck` implementation on Linux I've seen so far.

The `dmesg` output confirms the bad news: the disk is reporting a *media error* while trying to read the disk - so the disk surface is no longer readable at that particular block. It also says `Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed` so even repeated retries failed to recover the data from the failing block, so the disk could not automatically relocate the data to a spare block. A write operation into that block would allow the disk to "give up" on the old data and just switch into using the spare block for the new data, so the error may appear to "repair itself" as the disk is being used. But apparently the failing block contained important metadata about your `Downloads` folder, and that metadata is now gone.

That disk model (Samsung SpinPoint HD204UI) has been reviewed in March 2011, so this disk might be quite old. If it is actually older than about 5 years, you should definitely consider replacing it. Errors like this are your early warning that the disk is starting to fail by old age.

Comment: I Try sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 but i don't have any windows to check it :(

Comment: That is indeed worse news: according to `dmesg` the disk is reporting a "media error" trying to read a particular block, i.e. that block is no longer readable. If the disk still has replacement blocks in reserve, that error will apparently "fix itself" as soon as that block is rewritten (since the disk will stop using a failed block and uses a reserved spare block in its place), but you have lost at least one block's worth of data.

Comment: Thanks for the help. To just fix this I am ok to lose the folder 'Downloads' how I can fix it ?

The only solution is Windows fsck or format?